# php & mysql: confusion following code to determine new object's properties

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm a new to coding, and I'm having some trouble understanding a script that sets the new object's properties.  Please help me.  Thank you in advance.

First, in sign_up.php, I have a input element with POST method as such...

```
<?php include_once('classes/signup.class.php'); ?>
...
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="name" 
value="<?php echo $signUp- >getPost('name'); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Full name'); ?>">
```

In the signup.class.php, I have the following code...

```
class SignUp
function __construct() {
if(!empty($_POST)) {
foreach ($_POST as $field => $value)
$this->settings[$field] = $value;
$this->process();}

public function getPost($var) {
return empty($this->settings[$var]) ? '' : $this->settings[$var];}

}

$signUp = new SignUp();
```

To my understanding, the getPost($var) will return empty until the form is submitted.  Once it is submitted, __constructor() will execute the foreach loop and for the second time, $value will call to parse getPost('name').  This time around, what is $this->settings[$var]?

I am confused, and any of your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly does you confusion come from? `__construct()` is evaluated first, and upon POSTing, it will update `SignUp::settings` property accordingly. Then, when calling `getPost($var)` you will just get the value that was set in `$this->settings[$var]`.

Comment: i'm confused because the 'foreach' loop evaluates '$value' which calls 'getPost', where assessment of '$this->settings[$var]' refers back to the 'foreach' loop.  Also, i'm more confused because the $var and $field happen to be the same string.  I'm sorry, its hard for me to articulate my confusion, but i hope you understand..

Comment: Yes, the foreach loop evaluates `$value` but it does not call `getPost()` - it calls `process()` - which is a different function. Is this where your confusion comes from?

Comment: hey razvan, thanks for staying with me.  but isn't `$value` equal to `$signUp->getPost('name')`?  why does it skip the getPost method?

Comment: I replied with an answer trying to explain step by step what happens. Please let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code from `classes/signup.class.php` (with indentation):

```
class SignUp {
    function __construct() {
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
                $this->settings[$field] = $value;
            }

            $this->process();
        }
    }

    public function getPost($var) {
        return empty($this->settings[$var]) ? '' : $this->settings[$var];
    }
}

$signUp = new SignUp();
```

And here's what happens step by step:

1. The code is being evaluated from top to bottom.
2. The first thing that the interpreter evaluates is the definition of your class. So, after encountering `class SignUp { ... }`, the PHP interpreter will be aware that there is a class called `SignUp` but it will not execute any part from it yet.
3. Then it encounters the `$signUp = new SignUp();` instruction. At this point it instantiates an object of `SignUp` class and assigns it to the `$signUp` variable.
4. `__construct()` is now being evaluated:

   4.1 As `$_POST` is not empty it will execute the `foreach` loop.

   4.2 `foreach` simply iterates over each value from `$_POST` assigning it to `$this->settings`.

   Example: assuming that $_POST = array('name' => 'John'), then upon the first iteration (and the only one), `$field` will become `'name'` and `$value` will become `'John'`.

   4.3 Now the interpreter evaluates the `$this->settings[$field] = $value;` expression which simply translates to `$this->settings['name'] = 'John';`

   4.4 The `foreach` loop ends and the `$this->process()` instruction is now being evaluated.
5. At the end of the execution of classes/signup.class.php in your global namespace there will be an object called `$signUp` which contains an array member called `$settings` that consists only of a key (`'name'`) being set to `'John'`
6. Now the HTML part of your file is being interpreted and when the interpreter will reach:

   `value="<?php echo $signUp->getPost('name'); ?>"`

   it will simply evaluate the code inside the PHP tags: `echo $signUp->getPost('name');`, thus calling the `getPost()` method on `$signUp`.
7. The `getPost()` method simply checkes the `$this->settings` member (which was previously set - when `__construct`ing the object) and returns the corresponding value for key `name` (which is `'John'`).

Comment: Razvan, thank you for this clear explanation.  The part I'm confused is 4.3.  In my example, `'john'` is actually `'"<?php echo $signUp->getPost('name'); ?>"`.  Thus, after 4.3, doesn't getPost() get evaluated at this point?

Comment: Yes, `<?php echo $signUp->getPost('name'); ?>` will be evaluated in the end to `'John'` - but this only happens at `6.`. At `4.3` `getPost` doesn't get evaluated. The `__construct` function simply makes use of a variable that `getPost` uses as well (but `getPost` is only to be evaluated at `6.`)

Comment: Ahh, I understand now.  Thank you very much Razvan you were very helpful!